# linq order by two criteria

Tags: c#, linq

I'm having some trouble getting expected results from a linq query.

Here is some example data:

```
Queue Priority TTRDate
Main Critical 6/9/2014 7:41:00 PM
Main Major    6/9/2014 7:42:00 PM
Main Critical 6/9/2014 7:43:00 PM
Main Minor    6/9/2014 7:30:00 PM
Main Minor    6/9/2014 7:35:00 PM
```

Query:

```
listTickets = queryAllTickets.Where(y => y.Queue == "Main")
  .OrderBy(t => t.Priority == "Critical")
  .ThenBy(x => x.TTRDate)
  .Take(numberOfrecords)
  .ToList();
```

Expected Results:

```
Main Critical 6/9/2014 7:41:00 PM
Main Critical 6/9/2014 7:43:00 PM
Main Minor    6/9/2014 7:30:00 PM
Main Minor    6/9/2014 7:35:00 PM
Main Major    6/9/2014 7:42:00 PM
```

To put it simply,  I want Critical items ordered by TTRdate, and then I want everything else ordered by TTRDate.

Comment: And what results do you actually get?

Comment: @ErikPhilips "Main" is the Queue property.

Comment: @cdhowie indeed, the code proves me wrong, (but my statement is still correct! just not in context)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`false` compares less than `true`, so you need `OrderByDescending`:

```
.OrderByDescending(t => t.Priority == "Critical")
```

or use `!=` instead of `==`:

```
.OrderBy(t => t.Priority != "Critical")
```

Comment: `t.Priority == "Critical"` this would be false for all.

Comment: eee, I don't think so. Sample data states clear, `Critical` and `Minor` are the values for `Priority` column.

Comment: ohhhhhh, I was reading two properties `Queue` + `Priority` , together :) +1